# How to define a proof environment as in the picture?

Tags: indentation, amsthm, proofs, hangindent

First an MWS is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\lipsum[1]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

What I want is as in the picture:

[image]

Then how to define such a new proof environment?

Comment: You could do it with the `ntheorem`  package, which defines a `\theoremindent` length.

Comment: @Bernard But I use `amsthm` to set some other things.

Comment: Maybe there's a possibility in `thmtools`, which cooperates with amsthm as well as ntheorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `proof` of `amsthm` uses `trivlist`. It's not difficult to replace it with `list` with the appropriate `\leftmargin`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]
 {%
  \par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \list{}{\leftmargin=3\parindent\labelwidth=\leftmargin}
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape #1\@addpunct{.}\hfill]\ignorespaces
 }
 {%
  \popQED\endlist\@endpefalse
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{3\parindent}{1pt}% just to show the width of the indentation

\begin{proof}
\lipsum*[1][1-5]
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
\lipsum*[1][1]
\begin{enumerate}
\item aaa
\item bbb\qedhere
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the QED marker is in the right place (and you can use `\qedhere` in cases the automatic placement doesn't work, as usual).

Another advantage is that you can simply remove the code when you realize you're just wasting space.

Comment: In fact, I've tried similar ways to yours, but it brings about [another problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/657211/140814). Do you any idea to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

`latexdef -p amsthm proof` and
`latexdef -p amsthm endproof`
show that `amsthm` defines its proof environment like this:

```
\proof:
\long macro:[#1]->\par \pushQED {\qed }\normalfont \topsep 6\p@ \@plus 6\p@ \relax \trivlist \item [\hskip \labelsep \itshape #1\@addpunct {.}]\ignorespaces
```

```
\endproof:
\long macro:->\popQED \endtrivlist \@endpefalse
```

We can mimic the "Proof." part with a `\makebox`, and
use a minipage for the proof's contents.

```
\NewCommandCopy\amsproof\proof
\NewCommandCopy\amsendproof\endproof
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{proof}{+b}
{%
  \par\noindent\makebox[3\parindent][l]{\itshape\proofname\@addpunct{.}\ignorespaces}\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth - 3\parindent\relax}
    \pushQED{\qed} #1
  \end{minipage}
}
{\popQED\@endpefalse}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Two problems:

- The proof's contents won't span different pages, because they're all
  in a minipage.
- The QED symbol is placed on a different line.