# Using the new enumerate environment as desired in the new proof environment

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, proofs

First an MWE and its output are as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.3\baselineskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par%
    \normalfont
    \list{}{%
        \setlength{\partopsep}{\parskip}
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{3\parindent}
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{\leftmargin}
    }
    \item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape #1\@addpunct{.}\hfill]\ignorespaces
}
{%
    \endlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{newenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[newenumerate]{itemsep=\parskip,partopsep=\parskip,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,
    align=left,
    label={},labelwidth={0pt},labelsep={0pt},labelindent={0pt},
    itemindent=-1\parindent,leftmargin=1\parindent}

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{3\parindent}{1pt}\vspace*{2\baselineskip}% just to show the width of the indentation


\begin{proof}
\lipsum*[1][1-5]
\begin{newenumerate}
\item \lipsum*[2][1-5]
\item \lipsum*[3][1-5]
\end{newenumerate}
\end{proof}

\vspace*{2\baselineskip}
\begin{newenumerate}
\item \lipsum*[2][1-5]
\item \lipsum*[3][1-5]
\end{newenumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, I define a new `proof` environment similar to [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/657194/140814). Also I define a `newenumerate` environment to get the result similar to that outside the proof. While when I put the `newenumerate` into the new `proof` environment, the indentation of the lines without the first one is not the same as the result outside the proof. The picture as follows further shows what I want.

[image]

So is there anyway to fix it? Thanks you.

Comment: Why did you change the parameters? I only changed `\leftmargin`, *precisely* in order to avoid this problem.

Comment: @egreg `\setlength{\partopsep}{\parskip} \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}` could help me improve the space before and after the proof.

Comment: I don't understand. Sorry. Anyway, if you're using a nonzero `\parskip`, you're on your own, I'm afraid. And what's the purpose of `enumerate` without a label?

Comment: The purpose of `newenumerate` without a label is to get the result outside the proof. Especially, the lines after the first one should indent one more `\parindent` than the first one.

Comment: What I want is the `newenumerate` acts the same as outside the proof when I put the `newenumerate` into the `proof`.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot follow you.

Comment: @egreg See the new picture which shows what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by defining a new length which has the same value as `\parindent` when defing `newenumerate`. While I don't know exactly why this works. (It may be related to the definition of `\newenvironment` or `\renewenvironment`?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.3\baselineskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par%
    \normalfont
    \list{}{%
        \setlength{\partopsep}{\parskip}
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{3\parindent}
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{\leftmargin}
    }
    \item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape #1\@addpunct{.}\hfill]\ignorespaces
}
{%
    \endlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{newenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\newlength{\indentpar}
\setlength{\indentpar}{\parindent}
\setlist[newenumerate]{itemsep=\parskip,partopsep=\parskip,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,
    align=left,
    label={},labelwidth={0pt},labelsep={0pt},labelindent={0pt},
    itemindent=-\indentpar,leftmargin=\indentpar}

\begin{document}


\begin{proof}
\begin{newenumerate}
\item \lipsum*[2][1-5]
\item \lipsum*[3][1-5]
\end{newenumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg I solve the problem accidentally.